# Checking views and their default dependencies

Tags: sql-server, view, dependencies, ssms

Is it the default for a View to reference base tables in its own database in SQL Server Management Studio if it doesn't explicitly point to a specific database? I have tables with the same names across several databases on the same server and I'm not sure how to check which tables it's using. I used this query to see the Table_Catalog:

```
SELECT view_name, Table_Name,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

However I saw a warning that querying the sys.objects is the only way to really confirm the dependencies but I don't have a good query to see database information.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: See [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you. I found a query that helped me to see the references from the link you provided and included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view same as any query will reference tables from it's own database unless database name is explicitly mentioned with the table name like **databaseOne.dbo.TableName**

Comment: I wanted to add a query from the link proposed by @Charlieface. I found the Server and Database will be NULL if the view is referencing its own. 'SELECT 
    referenced_server_name AS [Server],
     referenced_database_name AS [Database],
     referenced_schema_name AS [Schema],
     referenced_entity_name AS [Entity],
     referenced_minor_name AS [Minor],
     referenced_class_desc AS [Class]
    FROM
        sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (
            '[dbo].ClientView', -- Add in table/view that is dependent to see its references
            'Object')
;
GO'